# Link to gallery does not work anymore in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I do not know how to solve the problem. I use wordpress for my homepage and in my theme I am using I added the "gallery" to my menu. 
The theme I use is called "Twentyfifteen". 
I created a childtheme long time ago and the gallery menu worked so far. 
But a few days ago I made changes in my YoastSEO Plugin, but naturally I forgot to make a saving before.

Now I tried to revert all changes (as far as I remembered) but it didn't help.
I also removed the menu and added it again, but this also didn't help.

Now my question is: How can I take a look into what is happening in wordpress after I click on the gallery menu? The link which will be executed is:

https://www.melys-hundestyling.at/type/gallery/

I also googled the problem and other stuff, but it seems I do not find anything either.

Thank you guys in advance.

Edit: After the answer of magenta I will look up the server logs and provide more information when I have it.

Edit on 2018/08/12: I searched how to debug wordpress and set the following values in the wp-config.php file and uploaded it to my server. Like it was suggested in the doc for [wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress):

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
define( 'SAVEQUERIES', true );
```

Even though when I click on some links on my homepage there is no log generated in the wp_content directory. Funny is also that the link above works just fine when I am logged in in wordpress and "edit my site" and test click on the link to show all my galeries. They are listed just fine, but as soon as I am logged out it doesn't work anymore.

I also tried to setup the homepage locally on my computer and installed XAMPP and Wordpress and VSCode and the PHP extensions and copied the actual theme and the database. But naturally all the links point to the https sites so testing is not possible yet.

So I still have to investigate (I just do not know php and the themes and there are a lot of php files in there) what is wrong and how I can set up wordpress to actually see what really happens.

But I don't think that the links in general are 'destroyed' as they work when I am logged in.

Comment: Could you please provide information why the question was downvoted and voted for close? I just need a hint where to find the information I need to be able to see how I can solve the problem guys.

Comment: I am not the person that down voted but you really have not provided enough information. Are there any error messages in the server logs or the browser console? Specifically, what changes did you make. I do not like to visit unknown websites for security reasons so it is important for people like me that a complete description of the problem is given.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The problem is, I did not have any of these information because I didn't think about server logs. now that I have this kind of information I will look it up and provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a setting in the "Yoast SEO"-Plugin where I deactivated the "author archives". This makes a change so that the link to ".../type/gallery" (see above) does not work anymore. Furthermore it was necessary to delete the browser cache to be able to show the site for that link again.